# Посчитать сумму столбца по неделям, и сгруппировать по id

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

В таблице есть поля : date, id, amount. Нужно достать запросом сумму amount-ов по неделям, которые превышают 96000. Группировку нужно сделать по id.

Comment: `group by date_format(date, '%Y-%U'), id` например. Или подберите более подходящую функцию для получения требуемого разбиения дат http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Date_and_time_functions.html

Comment: *сумму amount-ов по неделям, которые превышают 96000. Группировку нужно сделать по id.* А переведите это на русский, пожалуйста. Можно примером...